# How to make arrow key navigation on responsive card grid like google drive in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, responsive-design, grid

I have tried to achieve arrow key navigation in all 4 direction. I'm able to achieve 2 direction `left` and `right` using `nextSibling` and `previousSibling`. But not found any ways to get above and below divs. I have seen many examples for arrow key navigation on card grid layout but found not one with responsive design. When you have responsive support the number of cards in each row changes. In our case, we are having a single div with wrap to create the grid. I have seen apps like Google drive which have responsive support and arrow key navigation. [Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mountain-cn6bj)

Comment: You need to keep the currently selected index in a variable. A left arrow keypress simply decreases the index by one, and an up arrow keypress decreases it by whatever the current number of divs per row is.

Comment: Thank you for response @ChrisG, I'm able to do left and right card change with next and previous sibling or column change. I'm facing difficulties implementing the row change as there are no methods to find the above and below elements. Issue is that with every change in design due to responsive support I have  to update the attribute in elements. I'm looking for solution with less calculations

Comment: Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: https://ishadeed.com/assets/grid-flex/grid-use-2.png
Like shown in image. Let's say 1st card is selected and after that 1 want to change the selection to below card on 2nd row with down arrow key. So if the layout is remaining same I can use current + 3 nextSibling to do the same but In case of responsive design number of card can be changed to 2 in single row. So that's the reason I'm not able to do this in simple way. If still not got the idea let me know I can create a template in code sandbox.

Comment: What image? I don't see any.

Comment: `ishadeed.com/assets/grid-flex/grid-use-2.png` This one. Please open this link. I will share the code sandbox example by tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisG I have created the sample [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mountain-cn6bj) . I have added the key press events for left and right arrow key and responsive design with different card for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are sure all your cards have the same width you can go with the below approach:**
You can find the element above or below using their x and y coordinates, which you can get using the [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) , [window.scrollX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX) and [window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) methods.

moving forward with your [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mountain-cn6bj),
Add a getRect() method to your layout component to get the x and y coords.

```js
getRect = (id) => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = rect.left + window.scrollX;
    const y = rect.top + window.scrollY;
    return { el, x, y };
  };
```

Now add conditions for `ARROW_UP` and `ARROW_DOWN` keys to `handleKeyPress()` method

```js
 else if (e.key === NAVIGATION_KEYS.ARROW_UP) {
      const { x, y } = this.getRect(selected);

      // loop back in the list and select the first element
      // that is above the current selected element and has the same x coordinate
      for (let i = list.indexOf(selected) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const { el, x: tx, y: ty } = this.getRect(list[i]);

        if (x === tx && y > ty) {
          this.setState({
            selected: list[i]
          });
          el.scrollIntoView(); // scrolls the element into view, try removing it to see what it does
          break;
        }
      }
    } else if (e.key === NAVIGATION_KEYS.ARROW_DOWN) {
      const { x, y } = this.getRect(selected);

      // loop forward in the list and select the first element
      // that is below the current selected element and has the same x coordinate
      for (let i = list.indexOf(selected) + 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        const { el, x: tx, y: ty } = this.getRect(list[i]);

        if (x === tx && y < ty) {
          this.setState({
            selected: list[i]
          });
          el.scrollIntoView(); // scrolls the element into view, try removing it to see what it does
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

if you want smooth scroll effect you can add the following css

```css
html {
  scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```

I have added comments for explanation, you can ask if you don't understand something.

here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-mendeleev-9dz59) forked and extended from your [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mountain-cn6bj)